# Facebook API+setting password and username+PHP

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook

Is it possible in Facebook API wherein you could set your username and password statically?
For instance,

You'll set like this one.

```
$username = 'myusername@test.com';
$password = 'password123';
$secret_key = 'asdfsd2354fg1215';
```

The reason why I wanted this one because base on my experience, once you integrated facebook, it always ask for my password and username. I don't want to type in my username and password again.

I'm creating a website that allows people to use my account without letting them type in my username and password.

How would I do that? or any ideas.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded. Thanks! :)

Comment: No there is no such thing exists dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing Facebook programatically with a users email address and password is against their Terms of Service.  If you wanted to allow other people to control your account, you could get an access token (for example by using the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)) and then embed that access token into your application and then use the Facebook Graph API.